# React MUIDatatable trigger going to a different page after a row is clicked

Tags: reactjs, mui-datatable

I have a `MUIDataTable` and I need to go to a new screen when the user clicks a row. I want to allow only one clicked row. This is what I tried:

```
const options = {
  selectableRows: true,
  selectableRowsOnClick: true,
  onRowClick: useHistory('/app/proposals')
};
```

I also tried using `useHistory` but it doesn't look like the click is triggered.

The table definition is straightforward:

```
<MUIDataTable
   data={data.hits}
   columns={columns}
   options={options}
/>
```

To clarify, I don't need to row to be selected. I want to go immediately to another page.

Comment: If you make the onRowClick: console.log('clicked'), in the options const do you see the log?

Answer (score 0):

Try using useHistory() as defined in the [documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/usehistory)

```
let history = useHistory();

const options = {
  selectableRows: true,
  selectableRowsOnClick: true,
  onRowClick: history.push('/app/proposals')
};
```

Comment: This results in an error. Usually it's best to test your solution before proposing it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I implemented it:

```
const options = {     
    selectableRows: "single", // no multiple rows selection for me  
    selectableRowsOnClick: true,     
    onRowsSelect: function(currentRowsSelected: array, allRowsSelected: array) {      
         let selectedIndex = currentRowsSelected[0].index;         
         setLocalStorage("whatever data I need, based on the selected row"); 
         props.history.push("my_page");    
    },
};
```

Then in the table definition:

```
options={options}
```